# Highcharts: Remove space between plot border and actual chart

Tags: highcharts

We are migrating from a flash based charting library (FusionCharts) to a JavaScript based one (HighCharts).

This is what our current flash charts look like
[image: Current flash charts]

And this is what I've got so far with HighCharts.
[image]

How can I remove the space (marked with big dumb red arrows) between the plot border and the actual chart data?

Here's my code: http://jsfiddle.net/ChrisMBarr/7JAcN/1/

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart:{
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'areaspline',
            plotBorderWidth: 1,
            spacingTop:2,
            spacingRight:5,
            spacingBottom:5,
            spacingLeft:2,
            borderWidth:1,
            borderRadius:0,
            borderColor:'#999'
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Total spam in the last 7 days'
        },
        legend: {
            verticalAlign: 'bottom',
            borderWidth: 1,
            backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF'
        },
        xAxis: {
            allowDecimals:false,
            categories: [
                'Thu 2/14',
                'Fri 2/15',
                'Sat 2/16',
                'Sun 2/17',
                'Mon 2/18',
                'Tue 2/19',
                'Wed 2/20'
            ],
            labels: {
                staggerLines: 2
            },
            tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
        },
        yAxis: {
            allowDecimals:false,
            alternateGridColor: '#F7F7F7',
            title: {
                text: 'Number of Emails',
                margin:5
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                var isSpam = this.series.name === _chartOptions.series[1].name
                return ''+this.x +': <strong>'+ this.y +(isSpam ? " Spam" : "") +' Emails</strong>';
            }
        },

        plotOptions: {
            areaspline: {
                fillOpacity: 0.5
            }
        },

        series:  [{
                "name": "Total Mail",
                "color":"#339999",
                "data": [2,3,4,7,8,8,8]
            },{
                "name": "Spam",
                "color":"#003399",
                "data": [2,2,4,4,4,6,8]
        }]
    });
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This might help:

```
xAxis: {
    min: 0.5, max: 5.5
...
```

where max = number of data point minus 1.5

Comment: To explain the 1.5 - -1 for indexing starts with 0 , 0.5 is the offset on the both sides you want to get rid of.

Comment: I was trying to do it and made a fiddle with the working solution: http://jsfiddle.net/7JAcN/2/

Comment: Would there be a way to get the `max` number programmatically?

Comment: when you are gathering the data (you do it programmatically right?) you have the categories (this: [
                'Thu 2/14',
                'Fri 2/15',
                .. so on) in some array, the count of elements in that array is what you're looking for minus the offset 1.5 hth

Comment: Hmmm, yeah I guess that's the best way.  I was hoping that `max` would alternatively take a function. Oh well.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: `plotOptions.series.pointPlacement: 'on'` should work as well and feels a bit "cleaner" (see @SerNeo's answer, https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.pointPlacement)

Answer (score 8):

You should use minPadding/maxPadding parameters but it doens't work with categories. So I suggest to remove categoreis, use min value and tickInterval

http://jsfiddle.net/7JAcN/3/
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.minPadding

```
xAxis: {
        allowDecimals:false,
        minPadding:0,
        maxPadding:0,
        /*categories: [
            'Thu 2/14',
            'Fri 2/15',
            'Sat 2/16',
            'Sun 2/17',
            'Mon 2/18',
            'Tue 2/19',
            'Wed 2/20'
        ],*/
        labels: {
            staggerLines: 2
        },
        tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
    },
```

Comment: I had same issue and setting minPagging and maxPadding solved it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The best way to remove paddings is to add **pointPlacement: 'on'**

```
plotOptions: {
    areaspline: {           
        pointPlacement: 'on'
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With option "tickmarkplacement" set to "on", the xAxis "**startontick**" option might help you:

```
xAxis: {
    startOnTick: false,
    tickmarkplacement:"on",
    ...
```

see
[this jsfiddle, forked from the Highcharts API documentation](http://jsfiddle.net/martyk/T45rQ/)

Comment: @ManojSethi See the answer I accepted above.  I asked this question over 2 1/2 years ago at this point, so I don't really recall the specifics right now.