# Remove spaces between axes and columns in Highcharts with only one category

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I've a chart generated from a JSON with a lot of data but in only one "x axe" serie. I'm not very clear but an example is better:

[My chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgA9d.png)

I would like to remove the blank between the columns and the right, in order to zoom in. 
I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14991486/highcharts-remove-space-between-plot-border-and-actual-chart) but the solution with

```
xAxis: {
 min: 0,
}
```

doesn't work on my case (or maybe I'm doing it wrong..) because I have only one item on the X axe, the category "Students"

[Here is my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T45rQ/311/) (names are random)

Comment: You only want it removed on the right side? Not the left?

Comment: You need to set pointPadding / groupPadding as 0 and add pointRange. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/T45rQ/318/

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was looking for ! But I will follow jlbriggs advices and use a vertical chart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sebastian's comment should answer the actual question, but I have to question using this set up in the first place.

The category itself serves no purpose if there's only one - the x axis title can fill that role, and eliminate any need for adjusting settings to behave normally.

A separate series for each student is definitely overkill, and results in 5 pages worth of legend entries, which can never hope to be associated with the actual student's column, as there are too many repeats of each color (and you're simply not going to come  up with 73 distinctly identifiable colors, nor would it be useful to try...)

I would suggest a few things:

1) use a single series for all of the students. You gain nothing by using 73 different series

2) use each student's name as the category

3) forget about multiple colors - they add nothing useful, and there aren't enough of them even if they did

4) make it a horizontal `bar` chart instead of a `column` chart.

The result is a much more user-friendly display.

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/nx7z1387/

Also, if the goal is to show the values in a meaningful way, I would strongly consider sorting by value instead of by name.  I realize there may be some argument for sorting it alphabetically, but it really shows the data in a much more understandable way when sorted by value.

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/nx7z1387/5/

FWIW

Comment: Got the same problem and this does not solve it. How do you remove the space on the left and right? I only got 4-5 bars, but still do not want this space to be wasted. or at least control it

Comment: @EdmundoDelGusto you'll have to be a lot more specific about which problem you're having and what your setup is. A live example works best to show the problem and get a solution.